# Printing Pointer Value a Second Time Returns Wrong Result

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?
I'm studying linked lists. So, I wrote a function to insert in front.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct IntElement{
    struct IntElement *next;
    int data;

} IntElement;

bool insertInFront (IntElement **head, int data);


int main (void){

    IntElement *head;
    insertInFront ( &head, 10);
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    insertInFront ( &head, 20);
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    insertInFront ( &head, 30);
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    insertInFront ( &head, 40);
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    cout << head->data<<endl;
    return 0;
}

bool insertInFront (IntElement **head, int data){

    IntElement newElem;
    newElem.data = data;
    newElem.next = *head;
    *head = &newElem;
    return true;    

}
```

The whole program seems ok, but when I print the result for a second time, it returns a wrong value.

For instance:

```
10
20
30
1447361072
40
1447361072
```

Comment: you haven't init head pointer?

Comment: In addition, sooner or later you're going to have to dynamically allocate *something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the content of an automatic variable created on the stack and local to the function InsertInFront().  This variable is deleted when the function InsertInfron() exits. Then the head pointer points to some garbage leftover after the return from the function InsertInFront().

```
bool insertInFront (IntElement **head, int data){

    IntElement newElem;   <-- create a IntElement (automatic variable)
    newElem.data = data;  <-- Fill a IntElement
    newElem.next = *head;
    *head = &newElem;      
    return true;    
                           <-- delete a IntElement 
}
```

The following allocates from the heap, and such dynamic variables are valid after return from InsertInFront().

```
bool insertInFront (IntElement **head, int data){

    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;   
    newElem->data = data;  
    newElem->next = *head;
    *head = newElem;      
    return true;                  
}
```

Do not forget to initialize the head of an empty list !!!

Comment: Thanks for the information! I had previously initialized the head, but somehow I messed up and erased that. I had not realized that the newElem would be deleted after the return. I thought it would be still ok because it was pointed by someone in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your `head` element, e.g.

```
IntElement *head = 0;
```

Next problem is in `insertInFront`, where you use a local variable in your list. This local variable is gone, when you leave the function. You need to allocate memory on the heap

```
IntElement *newElem = new IntElement();
newElem->data = data;
newElem->next = *head;
*head = newElem;
```

I guess this is some study/homework exercise, otherwise I would suggest using `std::list`.

Comment: Thanks for the shared knowledge. It's working fine now.
About the list, yes, indeed. It's just an exercise I'm doing for fun, trying to remember old concepts I haven't seen in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `newElem` that lives on the stack inside the `insertElem` function. So when you print it "second time", it has been overwritten during the printing process. The first time works simply because nothing else has touched that bit of the stack.

Use

```
IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
newElem->data = data;
newElem->next = *head;
*head = newElem;
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the shared knowledge. It's working fine now.